# insert multi values from form to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

this is loop.php code

```
$compo = $_POST['compo'];
$fill = $_POST['fill'];

$totalCompo = sizeof($compo);

for($i=0;$i<$totalUsername;$i++) {

    $InsertUsername = $compo[$i];
    $InsertFname = $fill[$i];

      $query = "INSERT INTO `Invantsion`(`compon`, `Num`)".
             " VALUES ('$InsertUsername','$InsertFname') ";

}


if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

in the loop page i need to insert the data.
and this is the form
in the mysql i see the last result in the mysql

```
<form method="POST" action="loop.php">
<input type="hidden" name="step" value="save">
<input type='hidden' name='compo[]' value='DECODERS'>DECODERS<select name='fill[]'><option value='NULL'>null</option></select><br><input type='hidden' name='compo[]' value='DECODERS'>DECODERS<select name='fill[]'><option value='100'>100</option></select><br><input type='hidden' name='compo[]' value='rg59'>rg59<select name='fill[]'><option value='300'>300</option><option value='400'>400</option></select><br><input type="submit" value="שלח" name="ok" style="border: 1px solid #000000; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; background-color: #008000; font-family:Arial; font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold"><input type="reset" value="&agrave;&eacute;&ocirc;&aring;&ntilde;" name="B2" style="border: 1px solid #000000; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; background-color: #008000; font-family:Arial; font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold">
</p>
</form>
```

i mean  to this

```
<input type='hidden' name='compo[]' value='rg59'>rg59<select name='fill[]'><option value='300'>300</option><option value='400'>400</option>
```

what wrong?

Comment: Put your query inside of your loop, or else only the last one will run. Also, you are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The parameters and variables should be checked and sanitized before using in query.
2. You can take advantage of string concatenation in php and constructs a query for with multiple value rows to insert data. In this way, all of the data will be inserted by single query execution.

   ```
       $_POST['compo'] = array('test1','test2','test3');
       $_POST['fill'] = array('fname1','fname2','fname3');
       $compo = (!empty($_POST['compo'])?$_POST['compo']:array());
       $fill = (!empty($_POST['fill'])?$_POST['fill']:array());

       $totalCompo = sizeof($compo);

       $query = "INSERT INTO Invantsion(compon, Num) VALUES ";

       for($i=0; $i< $totalCompo; $i++)
       {

        $InsertUsername = (!empty($compo[$i])?$compo[$i]:'');
        $InsertFname = (!empty($fill[$i])?$fill[$i]:'');

        //Only insert if both username and firstname exists
        if(!empty($InsertUsername) && !empty($InsertFname))
        {
          $query .= " ('".$InsertUsername."','".$InsertFname."'), ";
        }
       }

       //Remove the extra , from the end of the query string
       $query = rtrim($query,', ');

       if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
       } else {
          echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
       }
   ```

Comment: Error: INSERT INTO Invantsion(compon, Num) VALUES

Comment: can you put `echo $query;exit;` before executing query? and show me the echoed string.

Comment: it recordind INSERT INTO Invantsion(compon, Num) VALUES

Comment: for($i=0; $i< $totalCompo; $i++)

Comment: I have edited my answer and now the code is returning a valid query string.